# how to define a class with a type family

Tags: haskell

[The following code](https://repl.it/MdIP/2) generates an "Expected a constraint" error :

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

type family Note a
type instance Note String = String

data SomeNote = forall a. Note a => SomeNote a

class HasNote b where
  noteOf :: b -> SomeNote
```

The error is `Expected a constraint, but 'Note a' has kind '*', in the definition of SomeNote`.  Why ?  How can I fix it ?

The goal is to include an instance of the Note type family in some data structure b, and use noteOf b to extract it, whatever the instance is.

Answer (score 3):

**The goal is to include an instance of the Note type family in some data structure b, and use noteOf b to extract it**

That's not how type families work.  All you've really said is that you can map one type, represented by variable `a` into another type via the type function `Note`.  It doesn't mean values of type `a` contain a value of type `Note b` at all.  It is the type class that rather strongly implies the `Note a` type is within or computable from the `a` type.

The code is along the lines of:

```
type family Note a
type instance Note String = String
class SomeNote a where
    noteOf :: a -> Note a
```

Even better, consider using an associated type:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

class SomeNote a where
    type Note a :: *
    noteOf :: a -> Note a

instance SomeNote String where
    type Note String = String
    noteOf = id
```